# Images not loading on one of the website page only alt txt showing(other pages are working perfectly). Currently using node.js, ejs for back end

Tags: node.js, image, routes, frontend, backend

I'm working on a website. All pages are working fine but on one page (brand-and-strategies.ejs), the images are not being shown (the alt txt is showing). I think that there is no issue with "src" value of images since these images load fine on other pages and even there images don't load on this specific page only. I suspect there is some routing issue with the backend although i'm not sure. The code is somewhat like:

:: FRONTEND ::

```
  <picture>
                <source srcset="public\images\services_assets\brand_&_Strategy\_hero\hero1.webp" type="image/webp">
                <img src="public\images\services_assets\brand_&_Strategy\_hero\hero1.png" alt="Hero 1" data-media="true"
                    loading="lazy" type="image/png">
            </picture>

        </div>
```

:: BACKEND ::

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public")); //allows EJS to access "public" folder.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get("/services",function(req,res){
  res.render("services.ejs");
})
app.get("/services/brand-and-strategy",function(req,res){
  res.render("brand-and-strategy.ejs");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bellow folder structure:

```
./public/images/img.png
./server.js
```

File: server.js

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
// the above line serves all the files from ./public folder
// so the img.png is accessible at example.com/images/img.png
```

this means the `src` attribute must be an absolute path

```
<img src="/images/img.png">
```

If you are on a page `example.com/services` and since you used relative path

```
public/images/services_assets/brand_&_Strategy/_hero/hero1.png
```

server is trying to load the image from

```
example.com/services/public/images/services_assets/brand_&_Strategy/_hero/hero1.png
```

which is wrong and you should see 404 Not found error in devtools.

To fix this use absolute path

```
<img src="/images/services_assets/brand_&_Strategy/_hero/hero1.png">
```

Also if you want to have `/public` in the path simply serve the public folder like so

```
app.use('/public', express.static("public"));
```

then use abolute paths like this

```
<img src="/public/images/services_assets/brand_&_Strategy/_hero/hero1.png">
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Mr. Molda! I've tested out and the issue was with the absolute/relative paths. I used this on the top of the page (before navbar) and image loaded. However, on its specific section, the image is not loading. I assume there might be some issues with CSS properties. I'm trying to figure it out, but anyways thanks alot!